# JavaScript Form Error?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have the following form. The JavaScript works because I have used it for other forms. Basically disables the 'Add Address' (Continue) button until all fields are completed. But I have added an address feature, where the user only types in their house number and street then the other two fields (town and postcode) are automatically filled (the JavaScript for this feature isn't shown as unneeded). So because these two fields are automatically filled and the user doesn't type in to them, the original JavaScript does not work and the 'Add Address' (Continue) button stays disabled. Any ideas?

EDIT:

I have managed to solve this. I have rearranged the form, by placing the 'country list, house number, town and postcode' at the beginning of the form instead of the end. It now works. Not sure why it makes a difference though.

```
     <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Payment Gateway</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ue1.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#firstname, #surname, #addresslist, #autocomplete').bind('keyup', function() {
            if(allFilled()) $('#continue').removeAttr('disabled');
        });

        function allFilled() {
        var filled = true;
        $('body input').each(function() {
        if($(this).val() == '') filled = false;
        });
        return filled;
        }
        });
    </script>

    <script>
        var placeSearch, autocomplete;
        var componentForm = {
        locality: 'long_name',
        postal_code: 'short_name'
         }; 
    </script>

   <form action="addaddresspage3.html" method="post" id="form" class="form">
        <div id="form1">

        <div class="row form-row form-bg">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-12 form-wrapper">
                    <form role="form">
                        <div class="form-content">
                            <legend class="hd-default">Billing Address</legend>


                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                                    <label for="first-name">First Name(s)*:</label> 
                                    <input type="text" id="firstname" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name(s)" required="">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                                    <label for="password">Surname*:</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Surname" required="">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                                        <label>Country of Home Address</label>
                                        <select name="title" id="addresslist" class="form-control">
                                            <option value="1">Select Address</option>
                                            <option value="1">United Kingdom</option>
                                            <option value="2">Saudi Arabia</option>
                                            <option value="3">Iran</option>
                                            <option value="4">Nigeria</option>
                                        </select>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-6">


                                    <label for="street_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">House number and street:</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="street_#Add#" validateat="onSubmit" validate="maxlength" required="yes" id="autocomplete"  size="54" maxlength="120" message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s mailing address." onFocus="geolocate()" placeholder="Please enter your house number and street">


                                        <p>

                                            <label for="city_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">Town:</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="city_#Add#" validateat="onSubmit" validate="maxlength" required="yes" id="locality" size="30"  maxlength="50" message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s mailing city." value="">       

                                        </p>

                                        <label for="street_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">Postcode:</label>
                                         <input type="text" name="postal_#Add#" required="yes" id="postal_code" size="8" maxlength="12"  message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s mailing zip code." value="">
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
</div>

</div>
   <input type="submit" id="continue" disabled="disabled" value="Add Address"/>
</div>
```

Comment: You should put only your relevant code

Comment: I think it's all relevant tbh @JoseRojas

Answer (score 0):

After setting the value of the input field, firer the keyup event of the field.

```
function setValues(){
    var my_field = $('#myfield');
    my_field.val('Alice');
    my_field.trigger('keyup');
}
```

In your case, I think is enough just to do this:

```
$('#firstname, #surname, #addresslist, #autocomplete').bind('keyup', function() {
            if(allFilled()) $('#continue').removeAttr('disabled');
        });

$('#firstname, #surname, #addresslist, #autocomplete').keyup();
```

Comment: I changed that from the original: $('#firstname, #surname, #addresslist, #autocomplete').bind('keyup', function(). Was that correct?

Comment: Where exactly shall I place that??

Comment: Just right after you set the value of the input field.

Comment: According to JQuery documentation the way to trigger the keyup is like this:

$( "#target" ).keyup();

Comment: The value changes every time though? because it's an address field. Different users will have different addresses, so the value will change every time

Comment: Yes, but you want to fire the keyup event even when user is not the one changing the information, so just right after you bind the keyup event just fire that event manually because you want the page to validate if the information is there even if the user pressed a key.

Comment: Still doesn't work unfortunately, still the same problem. Maybe something to do with this could work? function allFilled() {
    var filled = true;
    $('body input').each(function() {
    if($(this).val() == '') filled = false;
    });
    return filled;
    }. For example making it check if only certain fields are completed?

Comment: I have managed to solve this. I have rearranged the form, by placing the 'country list, house number, town and postcode' at the beginning of the form instead of the end. It now works. Not sure why it makes a difference though.

Comment: Good to hear that. I tested what I told you here. https://jsfiddle.net/dquinonez/bumebbys/

Comment: Maybe you had some JavaScript error. Try to put back what you changed and see the Developer Tool and check the console. There you can see if you have any JavaScript errors that prevent your code for running well.